# What does it mean to pipe from the Net Start command to the Find command?

Tags: batch-file, find

An example of this is:

```
NET START | FIND "MSSQLSERVER" > nul
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this command line does make a lot of sense, but any way:

`NET START` lists all running services, the output of this command is sent to the `FIND` tool, which searches for the string "MSSQLSERVER" in the input it has been given. If any line of the input matches the search condition find prints these lines an the screen, unless in a case like this, where the input is send to the null device. This is the part : > nul.

Comment: Aha! So basically, this is a way to figure out whether MSSQLSERVER is running!

Comment: @kalengi: Yes - if FIND returns an error then SQLServer is not running. If no error then it is running.