# Start a Windows service from a batch script and take appropriate action based on result

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, error-handling, command-line-interface

I have a .bat script that attempts to start a Windows service at the end.

```
:start_wildfly
echo.
set /p wildfly_service_name="Enter Wildfly service name: "
echo INFO: Starting %wildfly_service_name%...
echo.
call net start "%wildfly_service_name%"
```

I want to be able to interpret the result of the `net start` attempt so that I can have my script take the appropriate action if it fails (e.g. if the service is already running, restart it. If the service name is invalid, re-prompt for the name again, if the user doesn't have sufficient privileges, exit).

The problem is that the NET command does not return the documented  [Win32_Service class codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa393660(v=vs.85).aspx).

It does echo errors on the console, however:

```
The requested service has already been started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182.
```

See http://ss64.com/nt/net_service.html for a list of the errors.

Unforunately, the `errorlevel` variable is always `2` in these error cases, so I can't rely on that.

What I'm now trying to do is run a `FIND` on the output of the `NET` command, searching for specific error codes and act upon them.

```
net start Wildfly 2>&1 | FIND "2182"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto service_already_running
```

So, the result of the `FIND` is stored in `errorlevel` and I can check to see if the `FIND` succeeded by checking if `errorlevel` is 0. This works.

Now, the problem comes when I want to check for more than one error code. I don't know how to expand the code above to check for "2185" as well, for example, and goto a different label in that case.

I'm now attempting to store the entire result of the `NET` command into a variable, and then run a `FINDSTR` on that variable.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "output_cnt=0"
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b') do (
    set /a output_cnt+=1
    set "output[!output_cnt!]=%%f"
)
for /L %%n in (1 1 !output_cnt!) DO echo !output[%%n]!
```

This should store and echo each line of the output, however the last line doesn't seem to do anything.

And then I've also found some code that should search within a variable and return whether or not that string was found:

```
echo.%output%|findstr /C:"2182" >nul 2>&1 && echo Found || echo Not found.
```

I've had no luck putting it all together though. I just want to be able to interpret the result of the `NET START <SERVICE>` and jump to certain labels based on the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I want to be able to interpret the result of the `net start` attempt

> so that I can have my script take the appropriate action if it fails (e.g. if the service is already running, restart it. If the service name is invalid, re-prompt for the name again, if the user doesn't have sufficient privileges, exit).

Start the service as you are already doing:

```
net start "%wildfly_service_name%"
```

Now check the status of the service.

There are two ways to do this.

1. Use `net start` again to see if the service is running:

   ```
   net start | find "%wildfly_service_name%" > nul
   if errorlevel 1 echo The service is not running
   ```
2. Use `sc` (Service Control) to check the service status:

   ```
   SC query %wildfly_service_name% | find "STATE" | find "STOPPED"
   ```

   Or

   ```
   sc query %wildfly_service_name% | find "STATE" | find "RUNNING"
   ```

   The two statements above will return `%errorlevel%` = `1` if the text is **not** found.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [net](http://ss64.com/nt/net.html)  - The NET Command is used to manage network resources.
- [sc](http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) - Service Control - Create, Start, Stop, Query or Delete any Windows SERVICE.

Comment: Is there any way to detect if the service failed to start specifically because of insufficient privileges?

Comment: Looks like I can do `net session >nul 2>&1` and check errorlevel

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Comment: For anyone who'd like to understand how does `net start | find "servicename"` works, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10849838/3002584). I'd also advise adding the case-insensitive option: `net start | find /i "servicename"`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking DavidPostill's answer of using `net start` to check the status of the service, here is my new solution:

```
echo.
echo INFO: Starting %wildfly_service_name%...
echo.

:verify_not_running
net start | find "%wildfly_service_name%" > nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto restart_wildfly

:start_wildfly
net start "%wildfly_service_name%"
goto verify_running

:restart_wildfly
echo The %wildfly_service_name% service is already running. Will now restart...
net stop "%wildfly_service_name%"
net start "%wildfly_service_name%"

:verify_running
net start | find "%wildfly_service_name%" > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto start_wildfly
```

This script will first verify the service is not running.

If the service is already running, it will restart the service.

In either case, I check at the end to make sure the service is now started. If not, repeat the process over again.

Note that I no longer have a requirement to check that the service name was valid. The service name is now hardcoded earlier in the script so it is assumed to be correct.

And to handle the case of insufficient privileges, I added this snippet at the beginning of the script:

```
:check_permissions
net session >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo.
    echo ERROR: This script must be run as an Administrator. Please re-run the script from an elevated command prompt. 
    echo.
    echo Right-click "cmd.exe" from the Start menu and select "Run As Administrator".
    exit /b %error_level%
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right; the `net` command apparently always returns `2` for any kind of error. However, you can use the `sc start` command as a drop-in replacement for `net start`, and that one does indicate different errors through distinct exit statuses, in particular `1056` for *An instance of the service is already running.* So, you can use use

```
sc start "%wildfly_service_name%"
```

And then check `%errorlevel%` afterwards.